# Is it necessary to call Dataset.repeat()?

Tags: tensorflow

In [tensorflow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification), I saw dataset is just shuffled like

```
AUTOTUNE = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE
train_ds = train_ds.cache().shuffle(1000).prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
```

But I also see other people's codes like:

```
ds = ds.cache()
ds = ds.repeat() # ds is a dataset 
ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=1000)
```

I assume technically, dataset would be all consumed after each training epoch, and should be repeated to feed into the shuffle buffer for next epoch.

But why the first tutorial works without repeat? Should I call ds repeat explicitly or not?

Answer (score 1):

So, based on the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#repeat), repeat determines how many times the samples can be repeated in the given dataset.

```py
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([1, 2, 3])
dataset = dataset.repeat(3)
list(dataset.as_numpy_iterator())
[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]
```

Ideally in your case you won't have to repeat the dataset. Only if you want to go through multiple samples of it does it make a difference. And as per your shuffle, it would just shuffle the dataset after it has been repeated. And please have some argument or value in the `repeat()`, do not leave it None.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see wording like 'in the given epoch or training pass' in the documentation?

Comment: I used the training pass or epoch because it eventually depends on how the dataset is being used. If you are reshuffling at or after every epoch and kind of want no augmentation, you won't need to use `repeat`. And do not use repeat with the count empty, as it will keep on creating repeated instances until the buffer size is filled. Also I will remove the `given epoch or training pass` as it might be confusing